# Wrapper Object Explicit Creation

Tags: javascript

What i have understood about wrapper object is:if we declare a primitive type and access some properties then wrapper object is created internally and once the operation is done it is discarded e.g.

```
var str1="Stack"
str1.length=10
str1.length
```

The third line will give me 5 because second line operation is done on temporary object and third line will create a new temporary object.

But if i create my own wrapper object explicitly e.g.

```
var str1=new String("Stack")
str1.length=100
str1.length
```

Then also why i'm getting 5. Here i have no dependency of internal temporary wrapper object which discards on opertaion completion. Here i have dedicate wrapper object then why it is not allowing me to assign length value and if we can't set length then why Javascript allows me to set length??Could any one elaborate on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [javascript specification string length](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-string-instances-length) is unchanging. Therefore your code "str1.length = value" does nothing.

Creation of string via constructor--- var str1=new String("Stack")--- or via normal creation --- var str1="Stack" --- creates different types of object. But since their prototype are same (**proto**: String), length is still unchanging.

> length
>
> The number of elements in the String value represented by this String
>   object.
>
> Once a String object is initialized, this property is unchanging. It
>   has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false,
>   [[Configurable]]: false }.

See below example code:

```
var str1 = "Stack"
var str2 = new String("Stack")
str1 === str2
false
typeof str1
"string"
typeof str2
"object"
str1
"Stack"
str2
String {0: "S", 1: "t", 2: "a", 3: "c", 4: "k"
, length: 5
, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "Stack"}0: "S"1: "t"2: "a"3: "c"4: "k" length: 5
__proto__: String
[[PrimitiveValue]]: "Stack"
```

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for.....Damn i should have spend some time on proto also....Writable attribute i set to false this is the reason....I believe if i run this is strict mode the assignment would have given me an error instead of being so submisive.Thanks Atilla